# How to get two variables using MYSQL GROUP_CONCAT?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web page that displays photos `($file)`, below each photo is a list of users who 'liked' each photo.
Each user is displayed as an html link to their profile. Currently the users are displayed and linked by their user_names:

```
<a href=\"profile.php?user_name=".$tag.">".$tag."</a>
```

But I am wondering how I can display the users' name but link to their profile using their `$user_id`. Something like

```
<a href=\"profile.php?user_name=".$user_id.">".$tag."</a>
```

I am using GROUP_CONCAT in the query to get all the user_id's  `($tag)` that liked each photo from `tbl_collab` and then joining those results on `tbl_users` to get the `user_name` but I can't figure out how to display both the user_id and user_name in the html links. Can anyone tell me how this can be done?

```
//Database Query
$sql="SELECT up.file,p.user_name,p.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(cp.user_name)
FROM tbl_uploads up
LEFT JOIN tbl_users p ON up.user_id = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_collab c ON up.file = c.file
LEFT JOIN tbl_users cp ON cp.user_id = c.collab_userid
GROUP BY up.file";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    $user_id = explode (",", $row['user_id'] );
    $user = explode (",", $row['user_name'] );
    $files = explode (",", $row['file']);
    $tag_array = explode(',' , $row['GROUP_CONCAT(cp.user_name)']);

    foreach($files as $file) {

    //File is displayed here

    }
    foreach($tag_array as $tag) {

        //Links to the users who liked the file

        <a href=\"profile.php?user_name=".$tag.">".$tag."</a>

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your SQL get both values in your GROUP_CONCAT:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(cp.user_id,'~',cp.user_name) SEPARATOR '|') AS tagGroup
```

in your foreach for the tag array:

```
$tag_array = explode('|' , $row['tagGroup']);

foreach($tag_array as $tag) {
    list($uid,$uname) = explode('~',$tag,2);

    echo "<a href=\"profile.php?user_id=".$uid.">".$uname."</a>";
}
```

*(updated to use @Jakumi's comments and more example for clarity -- note i used '|' as the `GROUP_CONCAT` separator, as the character escaping issues for "\n" are cumbersome here)*

good luck!

Comment: ah, and a second comment: I would put the id first (presumably a number) in case the user_name contains a `~`. Then explode with limit 2. I had this problem once ... also one should ensure that the separator of the group_concat is something not ever appearing in the username ... like "\n" or something. (meaning `GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(...) SEPARATOR "\n")`)

Comment: This looks great guys. Just working though it. Am I right in thinking I must explode the GROUP_CONCAT first before using list(). Like this?  `code` $tag_array = explode(',' , $row['GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(cp.user_name,'~',cp.user_id))']);`code`

Comment: yes -- everything in your code remains the same, except the parts listed in the solution -- i suggest in your original sql use `GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(cp.user_name,'~',cp.user_id)) AS tagGroup` so you can refer to `$row['tagGroup']` instead of worrying about quote escaping and such.  also @Jakumi's other comments are worth implementing too :) (updated original response to include these modifications)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `GROUP_CONCAT` for this, just do an ordinary `JOIN` and use `ORDER BY` to get all the rows for the same file together.

```
<?php
//Database Query
$sql="SELECT up.file,p.user_name,p.user_id, cp.user_name as liker_name, cp.user_idas liker_id
FROM tbl_uploads up
LEFT JOIN tbl_users p ON up.user_id = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_collab c ON up.file = c.file
LEFT JOIN tbl_users cp ON cp.user_id = c.collab_userid
ORDER BY up.file";


$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$last_file = null
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
    {
        $user_id = $row['user_id'];
        $user = $row['user_name'];
        $files = $row['file'];
        $liker_id = $row['liker_id'];
        $liker_name = $row['liker_name'];
        if ($file != $last_file) {
            $last_file = $file;
            //File is displayed here
        }
        //Links to the users who liked the file
        echo "<a href=\"profile.php?user_name=".$liker_id.">".$liker_name."</a>
    }
```

Comment: In this specific case, I would agree. But not as a general advice, especially if the rows from the left table are very large and the right tables have many many entries to join, the amount of data to be processed would be way larger than with a group_concat. Also this gets unwieldy if there is another join with group by coming at some point.

Comment: @Jakumi There are certainly times when the GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(...))` solution is warranted, and I've used it in my own code for the second reason. But many times it's unnecessary.

Comment: I can barely think of a situation where a GROUP_CONCAT is warranted.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a very easy way to `GROUP_CONCAT` multiple values as per our requirement.

Linke in your case you want to `group_concat` two things

1. user_id
2. user_name

Then you just need to try this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(cp.user_id,' ',cp.user_name) as user
```

After that when you access this `user` value on PHP you will receive values something like this:

1. 1 user_name
2. 2 user_name

After that as per your requirement you can separate both values using `explode` method and get `user_id` and `user_name` on the array using this:

```
$user_array = explode(' ' , $row['user']);
```

It will provide you array value but in case you want `user_id` and `user_name` which you want to pass on `URL` something like this:

`https:://localhost/user_page/id/user_name`

In this case, you just need to change the parameter in `GROUP_CONCAT` like this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(cp.user_id,'/',cp.user_name) as user
```

Hope it will help.